# How to get the load test report for different user load patterns in the step up load test scenario in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

[Load Test Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwxpK.png)

Please find the attached Load test scenario for reference.

I am starting the load test with 50 users and it will run for 30 minutes, After 30 minutes I will add another 50 users and it will run for another 30 minutes and then I will add 100 users and all the 200 users (50+50+100 users) will run for 1 hours.

Once load test is completed, Apart from the default report, I would like to get the summary/aggregated report in the below order.

Report 1 : First 30 minutes (50 users load)
Report 2 : from 31 minutes to 60 minutes (50 users load)
Report 3 : from 61 minutes to 120 minutes (100 users load)

Can you please help how it can be achieved ?

Currently, I am filtering the metrics based on the time frame and doing it manually, it is time taking process so would like to know any readymade solution is available for the same, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) for this, i.e.

1. Report 1

   ```
   FilterResults.bat --input-file result.jtl --output-file report1.jtl --start-offset 0 --end-offset 1800
   ```
2. Report 2

   ```
   FilterResults.bat --input-file result.jtl --output-file report2.jtl --start-offset 1800 --end-offset 3600
   ```
3. etc.

Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)